Neovim: formatting YAML in a Markdown File (Frontmatter)
As it stands in my setup, Neovim (or, rather, Marksman LSP) doesn't recognize the YAML in the "front matter" as such. It's quite an annoyance with lists, for instance, as each item gets extra indentation when dashed form is used.
Example:
  ---
  tags:
  - foo
      - bar
          - baz
  ---

The YAML is formatted as expected when editing a YAML file.
Associating the same file suffix with two distinct file types doesn't seem to be a sane idea.
So, how to fix this?
